# Jenkins taking long time to detect slave disconnection

Tags: jenkins, tcp, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-agent

I am trying to configure Jenkins to reschedule a job if the job failed because the slave it was running on died (network issues, power issue etc).

My Jenkins has a parent(pipeline) job that calls many child build jobs. The issue it that a build job is not marked as failed/aborted for at least 15 mins when I manually disconnect the network cable on the slave when it is running a job. I have manually set the timeout to 3 mins under "Abort the build if it's stuck" in Build Environment but nothing happens at that point (Timestamp: 12:37). How do i make sure that a Jenkins quickly determines when a slave has died, and not wait for 15-20 mins that it is doing currently. You can see the timestamps on my dummy job which only prints 'Hello' msg:

```
12:34:32 + '[' 35 -gt 0 ']'
12:34:32 + echo HELLO
12:34:32 HELLO
12:34:32 + echo -ne '35\033[0K]\r'
12:34:32 3leep 1
12:34:33 + : 35
12:34:33 + '[' 34 -gt 0 ']'
12:34:33 + echo HELLO
12:34:33 HELLO
12:34:33 + echo -ne '34\033[0K]\r'
12:34:33 3leep 1
12:37:16 Build timed out (after 3 minutes). Marking the build as aborted.
12:51:52 FATAL: Unable to delete script file /var/folders/2k/2w2rvnys0hd1b105qxkb1_jh0000gr/T/hudson3917701081327223846.sh
12:51:52 java.io.EOFException
12:51:52    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$PeekInputStream.readFully(ObjectInputStream.java:2624)
12:51:52    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.readShort(ObjectInputStream.java:3099)
12:51:52    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readStreamHeader(ObjectInputStream.java:853)
12:51:52    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:349)
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.ObjectInputStreamEx.<init>(ObjectInputStreamEx.java:48)
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.read(AbstractSynchronousByteArrayCommandTransport.java:34)
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:59)
12:51:52 Caused: java.io.IOException: Unexpected termination of the channel
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:73)
12:51:52 Caused: hudson.remoting.RequestAbortedException
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.Request.abort(Request.java:307)
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.Channel.terminate(Channel.java:896)
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.SynchronousCommandTransport$ReaderThread.run(SynchronousCommandTransport.java:92)
12:51:52    at ......remote call to abishnoi3(Native Method)
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1545)
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.Request.call(Request.java:172)
12:51:52    at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:829)
12:51:52    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:985)
12:51:52    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:974)
12:51:52    at hudson.FilePath.delete(FilePath.java:1425)
12:51:52    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:123)
12:51:52    at hudson.tasks.CommandInterpreter.perform(CommandInterpreter.java:66)
12:51:52    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
12:51:52    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
12:51:52    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:206)
12:51:52    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
12:51:52    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
12:51:52    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
12:51:52    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
12:51:52    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
12:51:52    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:405)
12:51:52 Build was aborted
12:51:52 Calling Pipeline was cancelled
12:51:52 [BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
12:51:52 [BFA] No failure causes found
12:51:52 [BFA] Done. 0s
12:51:52 Finished: ABORTED
```